# Is access reader need UL approval for US market?

Tags: rfid, electromagnetic, smart-card

We are a access reader manufacturer outside of US. Do we need to obtain UL approval for our reader in order to sell or install in US?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is UL approval required on all items sold in the USA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10639/is-ul-approval-required-on-all-items-sold-in-the-usa)

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533406/ac-wiring-rules-for-switched-mains-output-device Products that are "installed" are required by electrical codes to have a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory (NRTL) listing and label. NRTLs include ETL, CSA and others in addition to UL. Consumers are strongly encouraged to buy only listed and labelled products. Retailers are strongly encouraged to sell only such items.

Comment: UL and other NRTLs have offices in many countries. Listing requires periodic inspection of the manufacturer's facility.