# Can I sell and install homemade smart light switches legally?

Tags: switches, ac, diy, code, legal

I have designed and made prototypes for a smart light switch. It involves inserting a PCB into the work box behind the switch and is powered by the household AC.

The goal was to sell these locally and optionally install them for people, and continue to improve and upgrade.

I assumed there’d be safety requirements, but I don’t know where to get a list of these, so I put that on hold until now when I’m almost ready to market.

I’ve also heard that in the US only a licensed electrician or the homeowner via DIY can work on the electrical system.

So, am I SOL for the installation part? If so, can I still sell them if I rework it as a black box?

Comment: You must be a licensed electrician to install them, and you have to get them approved by various regulatory agencies to sell them.

Comment: If you are not even aware of the regulatory requirements, chances are your device is not made according to the requirements and would not pass the tests without modifications. This includes safety and electromagnetic interference tests among others. So no, you can't install them and no, you can't sell them.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. Unfortunately legal advice is out of our scope here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question rather than a design question.

Comment: If your product causes a fire you could be held criminally liable under various laws. The homeowners insurance would deny their claim for a non UL part causing the fire etc etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AC Wiring rules for switched mains output device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533406/ac-wiring-rules-for-switched-mains-output-device)

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the device, you will need to spend about $15K to $20K to get it certified by UL, assuming it doesn't fail the first time.  It is a several month process.  For about $5K, you can get a review of your design to point out obvious problems before you go for the full certification.

Comment: Electromagnetic compatibility (i.e. FCC Part 15 compliance) often even harder than UL listing to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, nothing electrical can be installed unless it is listed and labeled by a nationally recognized testing laboratory. That is not a law, but is part of the administrative regulations of every jurisdiction. Local regulations also determine who can perform installation and repairs.

See also [AC Wiring rules for switched mains output device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533406/ac-wiring-rules-for-switched-mains-output-device) on this site.

Comment: Apart from regulation, perhaps worthwhile mentioning that UL is also required to obtain product liability or service/installation liability insurance, and reduces your liability exposure (because you will have completed reasonable diligence).